# Python Script will not retrieve all documents

Tags: python, json

I'm new to Python.   I have a Python script that will only retrieve the top two documents from a JSON API call.  I actually require the Product Sheet and the Warranty Details most.   How do I make the script account for the additional two documents that it will not retrieve?

As an example.  Here is the JSON snippet:

> "documents":{"en":[{"label":"Installation guide (en)","type":"Installation guide","url":"https://media.datatail.com/docs/installation/401298_en.pdf"},{"label":"Owner's manual (en)","type":"Owner's manual\t","url":"https://media.datatail.com/docs/manual/401298_en.pdf"},{"label":"Product Sheet (en)","type":"Product specification","url":"https://media.datatail.com/docs/specs/401298_en.pdf"},{"label":"Warranty Details (en)","type":"Warranty Details","url":"https://media.datatail.com/docs/warranty/401298_en.pdf"},{"label":"Dimensions Guide (en)","type":"Dimension sheet\t","url":"https://media.datatail.com/docs/dimensions/401298_en.pdf"}]

Here is the JSON configuration request:

```json
],
    "Body HTML": [
      "-",
      "description.en",
      "features.en.0.title",
      "document.en.0.label"
    ]
```

Here is the Python request:

```
# Columns with non-standard mapping or formatting are populated below. They are:
# 1. "Body HTML"
# 2. "Metafield: sf_classifications.product_details [string]"
# 3. "Image Src"

# 1. "Body HTML"
# Multiple and diverse values written in HTML format

for item in data['data']:
    specifications_en = item.get('specifications', {}).get('en', [])
    for section in specifications_en:
        section_title = section.get('section', '')

        if section_title == "Features":
            values = section.get('values', [])

            if values:
                features = '<p><b>Features</b></p><ul>'
                for spec in values:
                    specification = spec.get('specification', '')
                    value = spec.get('value', '')
                    unit = spec.get('unit', '')
                    features += f"\n<li>{specification}:</br>{value} {unit}</li>"

                features += '</ul>'

for item in data['data']:
    documents_en = item.get('documents', {}).get('en', [])

    if documents_en:
        documents = '<p><b>Documents</b></p><ul>'
        for document in documents_en:
            label = document.get('label', '')
            url = document.get('url', '').replace('\/', '/')
            documents += f"\n<li><a href='{url}'>{label}</a></li>"

        documents += '</ul>'

row[header_indices["Body HTML"]] = '<body>\n<p>'
row[header_indices["Body HTML"]] += obj.get('description').get('en')
row[header_indices["Body HTML"]] += '</p>\n'
row[header_indices["Body HTML"]] += features
row[header_indices["Body HTML"]] += documents
row[header_indices["Body HTML"]] += '\n</body>'
```

Still at the onset of the issue.  I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Note [mre] requirements -- a question should have the _shortest possible code_ that demonstrates a specific problem when run without changes. There are a few different sides to that: _Minimal_ code won't bother with things like HTML generation when the problem isn't related to HTML formatting; and _reproducible_ code needs to be runnable **without changes**, which this isn't -- it depends on `import`s and so forth that aren't included.